# How to use a batch file to delete a line of text in a bunch of text files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, text-files

I have a bunch of txt files in my D drive which are placed randomly in different locations. Some files also contain symbols. I want a batch file so that I can delete their specific lines completely at the same time without doing it one by one for each file and please refer to a code which does not create a new text file at some other location with the changes being incorporated i.e. I do not want the input.txt and output.txt thing. I just need the original files to be replaced with the changes as soon as I click the batch file.

e.g
D:\abc\1.txt
D:\xyz\2.txt  etc

I want both of their 3rd lines erased completely with a single click and the new file must be saved with the same name in the same location i.e. the new changed text files must replace the old text files with their respective lines removed. Maybe some sort of *.txt thing i.e i should be able to change all the files with the .txt extensions in a drive via a single batch file perhaps in another drive,not placing my batch file into each and every folder separately and then running them. Alternatively a vbs file is also welcomed.

Comment: Please can you explain the requirement to delete lines from the two files at the same time rather than one after the other? Both what is the reason and what exactly do you mean given that the hard disk will clearly have to do one at a time. Also, are you open to use of other scripting languages?

Comment: @ChrisProsser I just meant that it should execute as fast as possible.Its not necessary that it may deal with all the files at the same instance(may execute together for all files or one after the other,doesn't matter but should be fast).However with reference to the one by one approach i meant that i don't want to open each file separately myself and delete the specific line as it would rather take a long time and its kind of a hectic task and thats why i was asking for the batch file or vbs language.As far as the language is concerned I'm more comfortable with these two than any other.

Answer (score 3):

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file below.

It will search for every *.txt file on drive d: and remove line 3.

```
@echo off
for /r "d:\" %%a in (*.txt) do (
   echo processing "%%a"
   type "%%a"|findrepl /v /o:3:3 >"%%a.tmp"
   move "%%a.tmp" "%%a" >nul
)
pause
```

Comment: It depends on exactly what you need to do.  Can you describe the task?  `/o:3:3` means the starting and ending lines.  So to delete all lines from line 10 to line 20 you would use `/o:10:20`

Comment: very nice indeed......got it working by your method but i've some problems e.g it takes more time and memory and instead of just removing the third line it wipes out the whole txt file.i created two batch files one being the code above and the other containing the findrepl code that you referred to.am i doing something wrong or can the code be enhanced further to ease the process and be more accurate? and how did you include the pause command and what is its purpose?

Comment: by findrepl you mean the large code on the above referred page.....right???i copied that code.now the two files make the text file break into parts.for instance i'm sending you a text file which i'm using for the test purposes.try to delete its whole of the 3rd line with your code and tell me.

Comment: the two files are making my test files break into pieces and they don't specifically target the 3rd line.

Comment: http://www.cometdocs.com/download/801366-55526.txt   take a look at his file and let me know what you think of removing its 3rd line.its the toughest test file i could find for now.

Comment: That's a binary file, not a text file.  It's a JPG picture.

Comment: i know but its extention is .txt .can you apply the requirement on this file?the findrepl thing is not working with it but i'm able to completely wipe out the text even in the "BINARY" as you would say just by replacing "findrepl" with "findstr".

Comment: You do not change a filetype merely by changing the extension. You have to understand that there is a fundamental difference between a binary and a text file.

Comment: Your question isn't really suited for StackOverflow, which is designed to assist in programming for those that are a bit of a geek - you might like to ask it on another general forum like http://www.dostips.com/forum/

Comment: ok i'll do that from now onwards but please please help me out here.what should i do if i wanted to delete a single line in a bunch of text files(jpg converted to txt file as above) using a batch file and overwriting the old file.please help....

Comment: I also monitor the forum at Dostips - move the discussion there.