# How to get yesterday's date in a particular format?

Tags: datetime, batch-file, cmd, datetime-format

I need to set Today and yesterday's date in a variable in a fixed format `YYYYMMDD`.

For today date, when i did

```
SET TODAY=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
```

it worked and displayed '20190426'. 
But how to set yesterday's date so I get it in the format - `20190425` ?

Comment: I edited the tags. I want it for DOS but don't know what values to change above

Comment: There are a [lot of answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+get+yesterdays+date) on this site. Do yourself a favour and choose a language independent approach.

Comment: MS-DOS and Windows Command Prompt are totally different things, so don't confuse them! In MS-DOS there is no `%DATE%` variable...

Answer (score 1):

**Update** The original [unix](/questions/tagged/unix) and [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) tags were later changed to [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) and [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), which this Linux / Bash / `sh` solution won't apply to.

To get yesterday's date:

```
$ date +%Y%m%d --date yesterday
20190425
```

To get it into a var:

```
$ var=$(date +%Y%m%d --date yesterday)
$ echo $var
20190425
```

Answer (score 1):

There are literally hundreds/thousands of questions just [here on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+batch+yesterday).

I suggest you use a PowerShell one-liner for this, which you can call from a batch file as follows:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`
  powershell -NoP -C "'{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)"
`) do set YESTERDAY=%%A
```

`%YESTERDAY%` will then contain `20190824` when invoked on 25 August 2019, for instance.

A slightly longer variant, incorporating both `today` and `yesterday` in only one PowerShell invocation.

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\04\26\SO_55862158.cmd
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`
    powershell -NoP -C "'yesterday={0:yyyyMMdd}' -f (Get-Date).AddDays(-1);'today={0:yyyyMMdd}' -f (Get-Date)"
`) do set "%%A"
```

The PowerShell part issues two lines

```
yesterday=20190824
today=20190825
```

which are parsed by the `for /f` and set as environment variables `yesterday`/`today` respectivly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this batch/vbs hybrid, you need to save it as a `.bat` or `.cmd` extension file.:

```
@echo off
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "yyyy=%result:~0,4%"
set "mm=%result:~4,2%"
set "dd=%result:~6,2%"
set "final=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%"
echo %final%
```

Note, you can toggle the number of days in the `set day=-1` line.

Answer (score 0):

Previously posted answers are not pure Batch-file solutions... You may use the method explained at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050882/how-perform-arithmetic-add-subtract-between-two-datetime-timestamps/54054287#54054287) or just use [this simpler approach](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9037#p59237):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /A "YYYY=%date:~10,4%, MM=1%date:~4,2%, M=MM-100, DD=1%date:~7,2%, D=DD-100"
echo TODAY: %YYYY%%MM:~1%%DD:~1%

set /A "C1=!(D-=1),M-=C1*(1-12*(C2=!(M-1))),YYYY-=C1*C2,MM=100+M,DD=100+(D+=C1*(30+((M+(M>>3))&1)-!(M-2)*(2-!(YYYY%%4))))"
echo YESTERDAY: %YYYY%%MM:~1%%DD:~1%
```